# Creating a table with two different sorted columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created the simple table in a MySQL database;

```
CREATE TABLE `opportunity` (
  `customer` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bill_amount` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bill_amount`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I used 'bill_amount' as my primary key so I could remove duplicate information when I import data to the table, but I need to also need to separate records by separate categories as well. Here is an example of what I have, what results I am getting, and what I need. If anyone could give me advice on how to properly set up my table so it groups the data as need I would appreciate the help.

[image]

Comment: Not sure we understand what you're asking.  Where do you get your `Current table`, `Current Results` and `Needed Results`?  From the look of your `Current table`, looks like `DISTINCT` would get your desired results.

Comment: DISTINCT would get me the results via the query, but Im trying to normalize the data in the table when I import it. Notice the data (top section in my illustration)has duplicates in both bill amount and category. Id like to set up a table that will sort the results down to only one category per bill_amount for the same customer.

Comment: Think we're going to need more data to understand.  If you have a table with your example data in `Current table`, you can create a new table (i.e. `Needed Results`) using `SELECT DISTINCT customer, category, billamount INTO NeededRESULTS FROM CurrentTable`.